# Stop nginx ingress from serving fake certificates for hosts that don't match any configured Ingress

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx, ingress-nginx

I have a Kubernetes cluster with [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main). We use [Azure DNS zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records) with a record for `*.domain1.com` that points all traffic to our ingress controller.

I need to make sure that our cluster do not serve invalid certificates when someone requests host that doesn't exist in the cluster.

We have wildcard certificates for `*.domain1.com`, `*.dev.domain1.com` etc., but since we can get traffic for any nested sub-subdomain like https://super.fake.dev.domain1.com we can't have a certificate for double wildcard hosts: `*.*.dev.domain1.com`

I thought that a solution would be to redirect all traffic that did not match any `host` in any `Ingress` to some website, lets say https://google.com.

I can do that for http traffic, but when I'm trying to the same address using https it fails.

I created an Ingress like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: default-redirect
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      return 307 https://google.com;
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: does-not-exist
      port:
        name: http
```

When I open http://fake.dev.domain1.com in Chrome I'm correctly redirected to https://google.com, but when I do the same with https https://fake.dev.domain1.com Chrome shows: [image: incorrect cert]

I also tried adding

```yaml
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - "*.dev.domain1.com"
    secretName: default-redirect
```

But that didn't change anything (and wouldn't work anyway because host can be anything in domain1.com)

I can't use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/temporal-redirect: https://google.com` annotation because it's ignored when the `defaultBackend` is selected.

I tried using:

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  ~^.*\.domain1\.com$;
    return 307 https://google.com;
```

annotation but then the defaultBackend is hit without redirecting and 503 is returned because it doesn't exist.

I'm not sure what else I can do. Maybe I'm coming to the problem from the wrong angle? Maybe I should fix it somehow on the DNS level?

Comment: Did my answer solve your doubts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think redirecting to google is the right approach.
I'd pick a better http status code to represent the reality of the situation, a 421 perhaps... or a 418 if you wanted to have a laugh.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: I think I still need a valid cert to show 4xx errors.

Comment: If you get 4xx error means you have a client error. In this case he's not even reaching the client side.

Comment: Well the client did try and reach an invalid url.  Regardless, selecting the appropriate status code is what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser doesn’t recognize the validity of your certificate because your certificate is not valid.

The problem happens only with `HTTPS` because `HTTP` doesn't use certificates. Vice versa `HTTPS` expects the server to show a certificate, which the client will validate against its known trusted Certificate Authority.

You can run `kubectl describe ingress,certificate` to understand more about the error.

You will need at least one [Issuer or ClusterIssuer](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/issuer/) to begin issuing certificates within your cluster.

So, add the `Issuer` Kubernetes component:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata: 
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec: 
  acme: 
    email: "<your-name@domain.com>"
    http01: {}
    privateKeySecretRef: 
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    server: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
```

Check the issuer:

```
kubectl get clusterissuers
```

Finally, add the issuer in your ingress configuration, under the annotation key:

```
cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
```

Check the secrets `kubectl get secrets` and the certificates `kubectl get certificates`

PS: of course you need to validate the domain for which the certificate is being requested to a global Certificate Authority (CA), in case you don't have already.

Comment: We do have certificates for valid domains \*.domain1.com. The problem is someone can try to access \*.\*.domain1.com and we will not have a certificate for it, because double wildcards are not allowed.

Comment: But this makes me think I need to solve the problem outside of the cluster. I will never be able to have certs for all hostnames

Comment: Usually, there are 2 main ways: 1) wildcard SSL, that allows to add 1 level of subdomain (as you said only 1 level, not more for security reasons); 2) multi-domain SSL certificate (ex. SAN), that allows to add different domains. In your case, probably, you might mix these 2 approaches in one and use SAN with wildcards in order to do not have a proliferation of certificates. So, you'll have *.domain1.com, *.dev.domain1.com, etc. under the same certificate.

Comment: Not really, no. I know how to generate certificates. But in this case I cannot do it because of how certs work.